# Disabling submit Button after click will prevent submiting form in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

I have recently encountered, for me at least, interesting bug. We have made JS that disables submit button if there are no validation error in form to prevent multiple form sending etc. That works just fine in Firefox. However that wont work in chrome what so ever.

This was my logic for validating form and disabling button if everything is ok.

```
    $('body').on('click', "button[type='submit']", function (evt) {
        MessageBox.RemoveAllBoxes();

        if (!CustomDynamicValidation()) {

            //Something went wrong
            return false;
        }
        
        //Everything is ok. Disable button and send
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        return true;
    });
```

This works as intended for firefox. The Button was disabled after click and the form was sent. In Chrome button was disabled but form was not sent.

Answer (score 0):

I figure that if I place disable in Timeout it starts working even in chrome. Like:

```
    $('body').on('click', "button[type='submit']", function (evt) {
        var submitButton = $(this);

        MessageBox.RemoveAllBoxes();

        if (!CustomDynamicValidation()) {

            //Something went wrong
            return false;
        }
        
        //Everything is ok. Disable button and send
        setTimeout(function () { $(button).attr('disabled', true); }, 0);
        return true;
    });
```

My question is why is that the case? Why it needs to be in timeout even with zero delay for chrome to be working? Optionaly, is there a more elegant solution for this?